# Working with Checkbox column in DataGrid in Winforms project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid, checkbox

I have a checkbox column, and it is working just as intended.

How do I "get" the selected rows ?

I'd like to get the ones that are checked and run a method using another field of the same row.

Comment: Are you dynamically populating the checkboxes or are they static?

Comment: glad to hear the problem solved - cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it through:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item In DataGridName.Rows)
{

    If (item.Cells(0).Value)
    {
        MyMethod(item.Cells(0).Value);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe the answer would look something like:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DataGridName.Rows) 
{
    if (((bool)(item.Cells["name_of_column"].Value)) == true)
    {
        MyMethod(item.Cells["name_od_the_other_field"].Value);
    }    
}
```